# Change Node name of an XSLT based on an include file

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have a XSLT file which need to transform an XML file.

Sample XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Document>
      <Customer>
        <Header>
          <Message>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Header/Message"/>
          </Message>
       </Header>
     </Customer>
    </Document>
  </xsl:Template>
  <xsl:include href="Inc1.xsl" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now what I need is to change the node name Customer to Supplier depending on the include filename at the bottom and one more thing, I have specific attributes for the Document node also depending on the include file.

Thanks and hope someone can help me out.

Comment: "I have specific attributes for the Document node also depending on the include file." What does this mean? Please show us an example.

Comment: for example the filename of the include file is "Customer.xsl" then then the Document tag will have different attributes like xlsni=Customer and if it is "Supplier.xsl" then Document will have xlsni=Supplier, and same goes for the node after the Document tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only viable mechanism is to have the included stylesheet handle the specific element names and <Document> attributes: Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Document>
            <xsl:call-template name="apply-document-attributes" />
            <xsl:element name="{$customer-element-name}">
                <Header>
                    <Message>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//Header/Message" />
                    </Message>
                </Header>
            </xsl:element>
        </Document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:include href="Inc1.xsl" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the included stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="customer-element-name" select="'Supplier'"/>

    <xsl:template name="apply-document-attributes">
        <xsl:attribute name="foo">bar</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="customer-element-name" select="'Customer'"/>

    <xsl:template name="apply-document-attributes"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry I got it, I have a typo.. :)

Comment: Hi I have a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179184/change-document-attributes-of-an-xml-using-xslt) also regarding this.