# Change document attributes of an XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xls

I have an XSLT which changes the attributes of an XML.

```
<xsl:template namne="apply-document-attributes">
  <xsl:attribute name="xmlns">urn:iso:std:iso</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="xmlns:xsi" namespace="http://www.w3.org" />
</xsl:template>
```

My problem here is that I need to only have two attributes: xmlns and xmlns:xsi.

The code above is creating another variable xp_0:xsi="" and xmlns is not accepted by .Net.

Below is my preferred output

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org">
```

Any advise for this..

Comment: You cannot change the namespace of an element node by adding an attribute.

Comment: So, any idea how I can achieve my desired output?

Comment: Hi, right now my problem is to change the value of xmlns depending on the include file as in my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101084/change-node-name-of-an-xslt-based-on-an-include-file).

Comment: You give an element node a namespacae (or no namespace) when you create it. Study the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cElement_Declarations)